# Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile: Flow<List<*SomeModel*>> gets mapped to Flow<NSArray> in iOS

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-flow

My shared module contains Repository class which has two functions that return a list of items wrapped in a custom class extending `Flow` called CFlow.

I took the code for `CFlow` from [kotlinconf-app](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlinconf-app/blob/master/common/src/mobileMain/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlinconf/FlowUtils.kt) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64175099/listen-to-kotlin-coroutine-flow-from-ios):

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.asCFlow(): CFlow<T> = CFlow(this)

class CFlow<T>(private val origin: Flow<T>) : Flow<T> by origin {

    fun watch(block: (T) -> Unit): Closeable {
        val job = Job()

        onEach {
            block(it)
        }.launchIn(CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + job))

        return object : Closeable {
            override fun close() {
                job.cancel()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Repository example functions:

```
fun getData1(): CFlow<List<Profile>>

fun getData2(): CFlow<List<String>>
```

When I try to call this functions in iOS swift code the return type of the functions get converted to `CFlow<NSArray>` and inside of watch function the type of array is Any.

This is weird because  in both [kotlinconf-app](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlinconf-app/blob/master/common/src/mobileMain/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlinconf/FlowUtils.kt) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64175099/listen-to-kotlin-coroutine-flow-from-ios) the return types of functions are preserved and there is no casting involved in their codebase.

**Question:** How can I make the type of CFlow to be known in Xcode iOS project?

Android Studio version: 4.1.1

Kotlin lang and plugin version: 1.4.21

Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile plugin version: 0.2.0

Xcode version: 12.2

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because there are no generics in Objective-C. Arrays are ordered collections of objects.

So using any generic collection type in Kotlin, will lose it's type when translated to `NSArray`

I believe you have three options here:

1. Wait for direct Kotlin - Swift interop (which is postponed currently)
2. Cast values in Swift
3. Don't use generics with collections. I'm personally not using the Flow wrapper currently and doing something like this:

```
fun observeItems(onChange: (List<Item>) -> Unit) {
        items.onEach {
            onChange(it)
        }.launchIn(coroutineScope)
    }
```

Exposing a dispose function to iOS

```
fun dispose() {
    coroutineScope.cancel()
}
```

And consuming like this:

```
repo.observeItems { items in
    ...
}
```

But definitely this is more work and hopefully these interop issues will be solved along the way

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped to make things clearer

Answer (score 4):

right now the compiler can't understand nested generics. as a workaround for now, wrap your list inside a data class like this

```kotlin
data class ProfileResult(val data: List<Profile>)

fun getData1(): CFlow<ProfileResult>
```

it will give you a concrete type in ios

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped to make things clearer